# Create a set from a list using {}

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, set

Sometimes I have a list and I want to do some set actions with it. What I do is to write things like:

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,3]
>>> myset = set(mylist)
{1, 2, 3}
```

Today I discovered that from Python 2.7 you can also define a set by directly saying `{1,2,3}`, and it appears to be an equivalent way to define it.

Then, I wondered if I can use this syntax to create a set from a given list.

`{list}` fails because it tries to create a set with just one element, the list. And lists are unhashable.

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,3]
>>> {mylist}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

So, I wonder: is there any way to create a set out of a list using the `{}` syntax instead of `set()`?

Comment: `{a for a in my_list}`.

Comment: The short answer to your question is no.

Comment: Related (perhaps dupe): [Python Set: why is my_set = {*my_list} invalid?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36199066/3821804)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked a related question recently: [Python Set: why is my_set = {*my_list} invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36199066/python-set-why-is-my-set-my-list-invalid). My question contains your answer if you are using Python 3.5

```
>>> my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> my_set = {*my_list}
>>> my_set
   {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

It won't work on Python 2 (that was my question)

Answer (score 4):

Basically they are not equivalent (expression vs function). The main purpose of adding `{}` to python was because of *set comprehension* (like [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)) which you can also create a set using it by passing some hashable objects.

So if you want to create a set using `{}` from an iterable you can use a set comprehension like following:

```
{item for item in iterable}
```

Also note that empty braces represent a dictionary in python not a set. So if you want to just create an empty set the proper way is using `set()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
>>> ls = [1,2,3]
>>> {i for i in ls}
{1,2,3}
```