# Python Set: why is my_set = {*my_list} invalid?

Tags: python, set, keyword-argument

I am unable to figure out why this code doesn't work

```
>>> my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> my_set = {*my_list}
   File "<stdin>", line 1
    my_set = {*my_list}
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

`*args` is used in python to unpack list. My expectation was that the above operation would create a set but it didn't. Can *args and **kwargs in Python be only used to pass arguments as function ?

I am aware of the `set()` function but curious why this syntax doesn't work.

Comment: Related (perhaps dupe): [Create a set from a list using {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198829/create-a-set-from-a-list-using)

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus: It indeed is similar. However I would say that my question would serve as an answer there if we use Python 3.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to [PEP0448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/), these days it *does* work, but you'll have to upgrade to 3.5:

```
>>> my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> my_set = {*my_list}
>>> my_set
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

That said, `set(my_list)` is the obvious way to convert a list to a set, and so it's the way you *should* use.

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of set function but I was curious why this particular syntax didn't work. It looked logical enough to work.

Answer (score 0):

Following is a way to declare a `set` using a pre-defined `list`

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]  
my_set = set(my_list)
```

You would use `*args` when you're not sure how many arguments might be passed to your ***function***, i.e. it allows you pass an arbitrary number of arguments to your ***function***.

In conclusion, yes - `*args` is ***only*** used in ***function*** header prior to Python version 3.5.

Comment: @cpburnz I have updated the answer. Also, based on what you are saying - the accepted answer also does not meet the criteria.

Comment: @SiHa I have updated the answer. Please revise your down-vote.